# can't install nordvpn on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, vpn, openvpn

today I removed nordvpn and tried to install it again, I followed all steps that mentioned in the official website and still can't get it work.

```
sudo dpkg -i ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb

sudo apt update

sudo apt install nordvpn

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nordvpn
```

Comment: There is no need to `sudo apt install nordvpn`. The first command installs it.

Comment: I used to official steps on their website and it works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: yeah, but the commend `nordvpn` still not found

Comment: It is not found because you use the wrong command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you downloaded the `.deb` via a browser it should be in `\home\<user name>\Downloads`, `cd` to that location:

```
cd /path/
sudo dpkg -i <name of file>.deb
```

If it shows broken packages or missing dependancies follow on-screen instructions.

In response to below comments, seems like the `.deb` file just adds a repository but does not install the *nordvpn* package.So you need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nordvpn
```

as well to *actually* install it which wasn't clear to me.

Check for these two lines for a successful addition when `apt update` is run:

```
Get: https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable/main amd64 Packages [3,298 B]
Get: https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable/main i386 Packages [3,298 B]
```

Seems like the `.deb` failed to add the contents to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list`, so here are they

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
deb [arch=i386 ] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
```

Steps:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo nano nordvpn.list
```

Add the above contents exactly as they are without any "#" at start or end in a blank line.

Run`sudo apt update` then and `sudo apt install nordvpn`

Comment: the last two lines didn't show up after running `apt update`

Comment: Post `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list`,please.

Comment: `#
# NordVPN releases, stable
#`

Comment: seems empty, there's just a comment

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it needed to create a group named `nordvpn`.

(According to logs `journalctl -xe`. nordvpnd.socket: Failed to resolve group nordvpn: No such process).

`sudo groupadd nordvpn`

then start service:

`sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd.service`