# Unable to install NordVPN on Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, vpn, openvpn

Cannot manage to install NordVPN.

Tried:

```
sudo apt-get install nordvpn
```

Got back:

```
E: Unable to locate package nordvpn
```

I've read the following 2 questions and answers [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230967/cant-install-nordvpn-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230579/e-unable-to-locate-package-nordvpn), I've tried to dpkg the .deb file, but the solutions did not work.

If I ran `sudo apt update` without this line:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
```

I get no errors, but this results in no installation package.

If I add the line above (it is a 64bit system), I get the following:

```
Err:6 http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease
Connection failed [IP: 90.255.255.14 80]


W: Failed to fetch http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/dists/stable/InRelease Connection failed [IP: 90.255.255.14 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I *can* use OpenVPN, but it'd be much smoother to just use the NordVPN client.

Thanks in advance ^.^

Comment: "Connection Failed" usually means a networking problem, not an Ubuntu problem. Did you try opening that URL in a web browser? Did you do any network troubleshooting?

Comment: Can you ping 90.255.255.14?

For the deb it lists on the NordVPN download page to:
"sudo apt-get install {/path/to/}nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb" then "sudo apt-get update" then "sudo apt-get install nordvpn"

Comment: @ user535733 internet seems to be working fine, although the url results in a 404, I have changed the list to include /dists/ which appears to have the stable folder and Inrelease file but still nothing seems to work

Comment: @LinuxSurfaceNut just pinged 90.255.255.14

results in

`--- 90.255.255.14 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9015ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.401/20.164/22.214/0.752 ms`

Comment: What happens when you try the steps listed on NordVPN.com? https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-Elementary-OS-and-Linux-Mint.htm

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nordvpn

E: Unable to locate package nordvpn`